# apache mod_rewrite question / request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL:  `www.foo.com/bar/*.cgi`

in .htaccess, I need it to redirect to

`www.blah.com/bar/*.cgi`

ONLY if the subdirectory contains "bar"

What's the correct syntax to do .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bar/(.*)$ http://www.blah.com/bar/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Question:  In apache, I have scriptalias pointing bar to /some/other/directory   Should this make a difference?

Comment: @Paul: not that shouldn't change anything